# Create a nested array

Tags: php, arrays, nested

i have a table like below

- id

  - 1
  - 2
  - 4
- title

  - Home Page
  - About
  - Deneme
- slug

  - home
  - about
  - deneme
- order

  - 1
  - 2
  - 1
- body

  - Loremp ipsum
  - Dot sit
  - Color amet
- parent_id

  - 2
  - 0
  - 0

Now, i want to create nested array from this table. My function is like below

```
public function get_nested ()
{
    $pages = $this->db->get('pages')->result_array();
    $array = array();
    foreach ($pages as $page) {
        if (! $page['parent_id']) {
            $array[$page['id']] = $page;
        }
        else {
            $array[$page['parent_id']]['children'][] = $page;

        }
    }
    return $array;
}
dump($array);
```

When i dump my $array

```
Dump => array(2) {
[2] => array(6) {
["id"] => string(1) "2"
["title"] => string(5) "About"
["slug"] => string(5) "about"
["order"] => string(1) "2"
["body"] => string(241) "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam itaque cumque ullam eum atque consectetur voluptates veritatis sapiente voluptatem voluptatibus neque, commodi reprehenderit odit dignissimos omnis, veniam et deserunt incidunt!"
["parent_id"] => string(1) "0"
}
[4] => array(6) {
["id"] => string(1) "4"
["title"] => string(6) "deneme"
["slug"] => string(6) "deneme"
["order"] => string(1) "1"
["body"] => string(13) "deneme"
["parent_id"] => string(1) "0"
}
}
```

There is only 2 page list in array but there is 3 page that one has parent_id. Page that has parent_id not showing up. So some error in else block of get_nested function. What is this error ?

Comment: In the first iteration (id = 1) you see that you have a row with parent id = 2, so your else will be executed, filling `array[2][children]` with your row. Then the second iteration (id = 2), you have 0 as a parent id, this will then replace `array[2]` with your row, essentially overwriting the assignment done in the first iteration. It's a chronology issue but your logic is quite flawed

Comment: Hint: Put a `var_dump`, `print_r` or whatever, in every iteration of your loop to see what's happening at each step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thoroughly look at your code , you will realize when it first executes (`for parent_id =2`),

```
$array[$page['parent_id']]['children'][] = $page;
```

It will find $array[2] (`$array [2] ['children'] [ ]` ) doesn't exists. Possible solution is to `SORT (OrderBy) your query  in ascending order of parent_id.`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
try this:

public function get_nested ()
{
    $pages = $this->db->get('pages')->result_array();
    $array = array();
    foreach ($pages as $page) {
        if (! $page['parent_id']) {
            $array[$page['id']] = $page;
        }
        else if(isset($array[$page['parent_id']])){
            $size=sizeof($array[$page['parent_id']]);
            $array[$page['parent_id']][$size+1]= $page;

        }else{
            $array[$page['parent_id']]= $page;
        }
    }
        return $array;
    }
    dump($array);

?>
```

Comment: Be Aware:this will replace the $array elements where $page['id'] = $page['parent_id'].